# app return in log in 4s fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to Int because the result would be greater than Int.max but not in iphone 6

Tags: ios

I have my application which is developed in Swift 3 and xCode 8. my problem is when i am tring  to run app in iPhone 4s  is getting an error fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to Int because the result would be greater than Int.max. While iPhone 6, iPad not giving me this error.

Comment: You’re using a 32bit device. Maybe that’s a problem.

Comment: use `Int64` instead of `Int32`